# Can't access value from apollo response with Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I have an apollo request which returns some data, but no matter what I do I can't access the value and at this point I'm all out of ideas, maybe I'm missing something obvious, here's the request :

```
mutation MyMutation($jwtRefreshToken: String = "") {
    refreshJwtAuthToken(input: {jwtRefreshToken: $jwtRefreshToken, clientMutationId: "uniqueId"}) {
        authToken
    }
}
```

JS code :

```
const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(refreshTokenGql, {jwtRefreshToken: refreshToken})

console.log(data) // screenshot
console.log(data.value) // null
console.log(data.value.value) // null 
console.log(data.value.refreshJwtAuthToken) // null 
console.log(data.refreshJwtAuthToken) // null
```

And here's what the console returns for my first `console.log`, I clearly get some value back but my four other `console.log` all return `null` and I just don't understand why, I have no issue for any other requests in my project

[image: console screenshot]